# Find area of largest island (area not being returned correctly)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am working on [this](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/length-of-largest-region-of-1s-1587115620/1#) GeeksForGeeks problem that is looking for the area of the largest connected "island" of 1's in a 2D grid (details in question). I have a solution that works in some, but not all cases. My general idea is this:

1. Iterate through, row by row, until you find a 1.
2. Upon finding a 1, use the helper method to find the size of the island containing the 1.
3. Return the biggest island found in steps 1 and 2.

To calculate the size of an island, I recursively search each connected element (there are 8 of them), and flip each 1 to 0 when it has been searched.

I know the following are true:

- The islands are found in the right order
- Each island is summed only once (as it should be)
- Each 1 within an island is visited exactly once (again, as expected)

But for whatever reason, despite visiting all the 1's within an island, the sum of these islands are not properly returned. I'm looking for help to figure out why. I have tried examining each step of the process using print statements etc., But still cannot find out what's wrong.As an example, on this grid

```
0 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0
```

my code returns 3, but it should return 8. Can anyone see my mistake? My code is attached below.

```
class Solution:

    #Function to find unit area of the largest region of 1s.
    def findMaxArea(self, grid):
        curr_max = 0
        for i in range(0, len(grid)):
            for j in range(0, len(grid[i])):
                if grid[i][j] == 0:
                    continue
                else:
                    curr_island_size = self.helper(i, j, grid)
                    if curr_island_size > curr_max:
                        curr_max = curr_island_size
        return curr_max
    
    def helper(self, row, column, grid):
        if row == -1 or column == -1:
            return 0 # outside of grid 
        elif column >= len(grid[0]) or row >= len(grid):
            return 0 # outside of grid
        elif grid[row][column] == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            grid[row][column] = 0
            up_left = self.helper(row - 1, column - 1, grid)
            mid_left = self.helper(row, column - 1, grid)
            down_left = self.helper(row + 1, column - 1, grid)
            up = self.helper(row - 1, column, grid)
            down = self.helper(row + 1, column, grid)
            up_right = self.helper(row - 1, column + 1, grid)
            mid_right = self.helper(row, column + 1, grid)
            down_right = self.helper(row + 1, column + 1, grid) 
            return 1 + sum([up_left, mid_left, up, down, up_right, mid_right, down_right])
```

Comment: You're not including `down_left` in your sum.

Comment: Wow. I was stuck on this for far longer than I would care to admit. Thank you!!!

Comment: You could simplify the `helper` function to a true `dfs` to handle more generalized cases - eg. how many islands, each's size... too.